# How to implement a slide down setting view in a sidebar view, jut like Gmail on iOS

Tags: ios, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am searching for a easy or good way to implement a slide down setting view in sidebar view, just like what Gmail did on iOS. If you click the small down arrow on Gmail's side bar view, it will show a setting view with animation down to the bottom.

I am using SWRevealViewController for side bar implementation.

Want hear from you masters how to start implement it especially based on SWRevealViewController

Comment: take this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/), it help to u

Comment: this is not what I need. I need a 'slide down' menu on the side bar menu, for example, If I put a 'setting' button on top left of side bar view, it will simply slide down.

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple just follow the sample app with SWRevealviewController

Comment: this is not the answer, plz add your answer to comment

Comment: I searched the sample, where is the 'slide down' menu?